# past continues confusion [I heard you say/saying that] [I had him do/doing that]

Tags: past-continuous, continuous

I'll try to keep it short this time.  There are certain phrases I still don't understand how to use.

For example:

> 'Last night when we ate dinner, I heard you say something rude'

or

> 'I had Marcus paint the walls in the living room'

Almost every ESL student, including me, wants to use the continuous form in cases like the above and I think this is due to the incoherent explanation of the past continuous form of some grammar books/websites. I have yet to find a sufficient explanation as to why native speakers never use the continuous form in this case. Could anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that you can indeed use the continuous in both examples, but they mean different things!

> *saying something rude*

In this case, I was saying multiple things over a period of time. Imagine, as an example, I went on about someone's outfit. I didn't limit it to merely calling it ugly, but I went on to mock the color design and called the person wearing it pretentious. It might have lasted thirty seconds, or it might have lasted twenty minutes, but it wasn't singular.

> *say something rude*

This is typically reserved for single words or phrases. Perhaps you overheard me blurt out a swear word ("Damn-ugly sweater!") or perhaps you mean the sentence as a whole was rude ("That's a damn-ugly sweater!"), but it doesn't matter, because it did not have a particularly lengthy duration.

---

> *I had Marcus paint the walls*

You want to use the simple present when you have a limited object to be painted. There's a wall (or two), the amount is exact, and when he's done, he's done. Typically we think of the event as singular. You would say "I had him paint me a portrait" if a) the portrait is finished (because of the *had*) and b) you commissioned the piece, and the artist finished it. On the other hand:

> *I had Marcus painting the walls* / *I had him painting me a portrait*

With these sentences, it appears that you *made* Marcus/the artist to do something for an extended period of time. It does not imply, unlike the first, that you *ordered* them. In fact, the implication is that, because the event is no longer singular, that you were just keeping them busy and taking up their time by painting. You wanted to achieve not painted walls or a portrait, but that they were occupied.

---

This is all in the indirect. Perhaps turning it into a direct statement would make things clearer?

Compare the following pairs:

> You said something rude. | You were saying something rude.

The former consists of one thing said, whether it's a single word or statement. The latter implies some length and duration to the speech.

> Marcus painted the walls. | Marcus was painting the walls.

The former have completed walls painted. The latter refers to what Marcus was doing with his time, and the walls are not yet finished.

---

In sum, we have a big time difference, but because of it small implications arise in their different usages.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have to read your comment a couple times because to me, especially the very last example, both, non-continuous and continuous sound the same to my German ears. There is literally no difference for me. 'Marcus was painting the walls' doesn't imply that he finished but it also doesn't tell you that he did not finish.

Comment: And even expressing just a word takes up some time, so it's a duration for me. Do you get where I'm coming from?

Comment: What  if a person says a certain thing out of habit (e.g. people here in California tend you throw in the word 'like' a hundred times in every sentence) and when you point it out because they don't believe that would it be right to say ' I heard you saying it in the past'?

Comment: I would use ' er war malen'  to imply that he did something while something else was going on or if someone asked me ' Where was Marcus last night?'  I would answer ' Er war malen'.  Germans tend to use the 'continuous' all the time because ' er malte' sounds so poetic, e.g. 'Er malte ein Bild als ich ihn das erste mal traf' . In colloquial German most people would say ' Er hat ein Bild gemalt als ich ihn das erste mal getroffen hab'. This is why I can't get the hang of the English tenses.

Comment: I was shopping today and the person I was with was looking for a sweater for her uncle. She saw a nice blue sweater and since I know her uncle she asked me "You have seen him wear blue before, right?". My question is, would it also be right to say 'You have seen him wearing blue before' ?